# Baseline Environment with Azure

Tags: azure

Can someone please let me know how do I baseline environment with Azure ? If we have several VMs in Azure subscription can I baseline the whole subscription or VM ?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "baseline"?

Comment: It's like when you deploy/create an environment in Azure (using chef recipes etc.) how do you baseline an environment such that when you make changes to the environment, you should be able to compare it previous baseline and see the difference. It's just like creating labels in repository.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that you can "baseline" an environment.

The first is using ARM templates.  Please see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates).  Essentially this is a declarative way to define Azure ARM resources.  You can then make incremental updates to the templates and deploy it.  It is important to note that ARM templates target resource groups.  You could create one for each resource group you have, or you could also create ARM templates for individual resources and then run them in "incremental" mode.

Another way to accomplish this is through the use of Powershell DSC.  There were experimental DSC modules released for Azure.  See [this github project](https://github.com/PowerShell/xAzure) for more info.

There are pros and cons to each approach above that generally line up with what types of resources you are using, your language of choice (powershell vs json), and the automation engine you are wishing to use.

Comment: So with that I can go ahead and create/configure my environment and create VMs. Once I have script ready I'll run those scripts and create a VM that will be placed somewhere in Azure Storage area ? is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Sorry, the VM itself, or the Scripts to provision the VM?  ARM templates are run locally.  You can use extensions to post-configure VMs using chef/DSC/powershell which would require you to upload your scripts somewhere where Azure can access it.

Comment: Was this answer helpful to you?  If so, could you please mark it as correct?